# Expand Dataframe with Lists in the columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

In Python, how do I expand this dataframe...

| sect_id | sector | func_list | func_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAA | ['A', 'B'] | [1,2] |
| 1 | BBB | ['C', 'D'] | [3,4] |

To this format?

| sect_id | sector | func_list | func_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAA | A | 1 |
| 0 | AAA | B | 2 |
| 1 | BBB | C | 3 |
| 1 | BBB | D | 4 |

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

# apply ast.literal_eval if necessary:
df["func_list"] = df["func_list"].apply(literal_eval)
df["func_id"] = df["func_id"].apply(literal_eval)

print(df.explode(["func_list", "func_id"]))
```

Prints:

```
   sect_id sector func_list func_id
0        0    AAA         A       1
0        0    AAA         B       2
1        1    BBB         C       3
1        1    BBB         D       4
```

Comment: This solution is perfect and easy to understand. Thanks Andrej! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_clipboard()

import ast

def unlist_stringlist(stringlst):
    x = stringlst
    x = ast.literal_eval(x)
    return(x)

df_tmp=[]
for i in range(len(table)):
    sctid = table.sect_id.values[i]
    sct = table.sector.values[i]
    funclist_tmp = unlist_stringlist(table['func_list'][i])
    funcid_tmp = unlist_stringlist(table['func_id'][i])
    len_stringlist = len(funclist_tmp)
    for j in range(len_stringlist):
        df_tmp.append([sctid,sct,funclist_tmp[j],funcid_tmp[j]])

df_result = pd.DataFrame(df_tmp)
df_result.columns = table.columns
df_result
```

This would work.

Comment: Thanks for helping Suhan. Andrej's solution above works just as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `explode` with pandas 1.3.0+ with [multi-column explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df.explode(['func_list', 'func_id'])
```

Output:

```
   sect_id sector func_list func_id
0        0    AAA         A       1
0        0    AAA         B       2
1        1    BBB         C       3
1        1    BBB         D       4
```

Given, df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sect_id': [0, 1], 
                   'sector' : ['AAA', 'BBB'], 
                   'func_list': [['A', 'B'],['C', 'D']],
                   'func_id': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]})
```